# Construction of autocorrelation matrix

Tags: autocorrelation, matrix

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation_matrix) the autocorrelation matrix is defined as follows:

$$
\mathrm{R}_x = E[x x^H] = \begin{bmatrix}
R_{xx}(0) & R^*_{xx}(1) & \cdots & R_{xx}^*(N-1)\\
R_{xx}(1) & R_{xx}(0) & \cdots & R_{xx}^*(N-2)\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
R_{xx}(N-1) & R_{xx}(N-2) & \cdots & R_{xx}(0)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

However if I try to derive this scheme myself I don't end up receiving the same result:
Let $x$ be a random vector with $N$ samples in $\mathbb{R}^D$ (and therefore dimension $D$). In addition we denote by $x_i^j$ the $j$th component of the $i$th sample of $x$. Then I get:
$$
E[x x^H] = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N}x x^H \\
\Rightarrow \mathrm{R}_{x_{i, j}} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^{N}x_k^i x_k^j
$$
Where $\mathrm{R}_{x_{i, j}}$ is the entry at row $i$ and column $j$ of my result of the autocorrelation matrix.
So as an overview I get:
$$
\mathrm{R}_x = \frac{1}{N} \begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{k=1}^{N}x_k^1 x_k^1 & \sum_{k=1}^{N}x_k^1 x_k^2 & \cdots & \sum_{k=1}^{N}x_k^1 x_k^D\\
\sum_{k=1}^{N}x_k^2 x_k^1 & \sum_{k=1}^{N}x_k^2 x_k^2 & \cdots & \sum_{k=1}^{N}x_k^2 x_k^D\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\sum_{k=1}^{N}x_k^D x_k^1 & \sum_{k=1}^{N}x_k^D x_k^2 & \cdots & \sum_{k=1}^{N}x_k^D x_k^D
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This is obviously not a Toeplitz matrix in general, as you already see by looking at the diagonal.
In principle I get a matrix whose $(i, j)$ entry is the cross correlation between $x^i$ and $x^j$ without lag (which is denoted by $R_{x^ix^j}(0)$) scaled with $\frac{1}{N}$. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are biting off more than you can chew. Try it for the case of $x$ being an ordinary univariate random variable, and when you start generalizing to vectors $\mathbf x$, remember than $E[\mathbf{xx}^H]$ is itself a $D\times D$ matrix of expectations of products of random variables, and not the stuff you have written.

Comment: But that is exactly what I have written, as according to wikipedia $E[xx^H] = \mathrm{R}_x$.

Comment: Well, no. There are lots of things missing from your garbled presentation such as the source of your claimed autocorrelation matrix which is clearly for _complex-valued random variables that are from a discrete-time _wide-sense-stationary (a.k.a weakly stationary) stochastic process (a.k.a time series) without which the Toeplitz form is not seen, etc.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to tell me. All I am trying is to understand how one can express the autocorrelation matrix as stated by Wikipedia, i.e. how I get from E[xx^H] to the provided expression.
And yes, it works generally with complex-valued random variables, which however means it should also work for real-valued random variables.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a problem on another site that has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if the Wikipedia article was wrong and has now been updated. My derivation now results in the same matrix as stated at Wikipedia.